# Laravel set JWT token into authentication header

Tags: angularjs, laravel, jwt

I am using JWT token based authentication with Laravel/ AngularJS for the application. 
At the current stage, users can log in, and token will be generated and saved in local storage (please see screenshot). 
[image]
And I have tested the API, it works with the token from local storage (please see screenshot). 
[image]
Now, what I need to do is to redirect user after login.

```
app.controller('AuthController', ['$auth', '$state', '$location', '$window', function($auth, $state, $location, $window){
var vm = this;

vm.login = function() {

    var credentials = {
        name: vm.name,
        password: vm.password
    };

    // Use Satellizer's $auth service to login
    $auth.login(credentials)
        .then(function(data) {

            // If login is successful, redirect to the users state
            //$state.go('users', {});
            $window.location.href = 'api/project';
        }).catch(function(data){
            console.log('error', data);
            alert('WRONG!!!!!');
    });

}

}]);
```

But it doesn't work. 
Because in the request header, the token is NOT included in the request header as authorization. So it returns error, token not provided.

Help, PLEASE!!!!

[EDIT]
Have done some search, now noticed that $http will set header with token automatically. 
But here I only just redirect the page, didn't use $http.

Comment: Can you tell us what is performing the authorization on your backend?  Is it expecting a bearer token in the Authorization header?  P.S. I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com), we are an authentication solution for full-stack apps and we have Laravel support as well.  We might be able to help you out with one of our libraries :)

Comment: I have used this link http://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs Worked perfect for me, cross check with your authentication code.